# Downgrade from ubuntu 11.04 to 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, reinstall, downgrade

I'd like to return from ubuntu 11.04 64-bit to 10.04 LTS 64-bit and as I **S** -ed **TFW** I've found only reinstal option which I'd tried before.

My problem is that I'm using dual-boot with Win Vista 32-bit, one NTFS partition with Vista, one partiton with NTFS for data and one for ubuntu. Live-CD installer gives me only complete reinstall on one whole disc, adding new partition and user defined.

Please how can I remove/clean ubuntu partition and re-install old version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot downgrade your existing Ubuntu System. You have to remove the entire system first - Use the installer CD for 10.04 LTS and delete the Linux Partitions used by your 11.04 Installation. After that, restart the installer, i'm pretty sure the guided partitioning will then suggest to you to use the unpartitioned space for your new Ubuntu installation.

Comment: You can also do this from Vista, using disk management in the control panel.

Comment: I know that downgrade is done only by reinstallation and I've installed ubuntu on unpartioned part. Is there any guide to work with partitions? I really do not want to loose my data again and install all things form start.

Comment: @Crowley reinstallation == loosing all your data on the linux partition. It is not recommended to install a linux system over an existing linux system without erasing it first, since it might run into conflicts with the existing files that haven't been overwritten during the installation process. Apart from that, most installation procedures are not designed for this (hence permissions of folders and files might be wrong after installation etc). Do a backup of the data on your linux partition, remove the partition and reinstall. Windows won't (shouldn't) be affected.

Comment: Your *(should't)* is the point I'm afraid of. Maybe I wasn't precise in words - I meant not damaging the Data and Win partitons.

Comment: I have performed this procedure several times. The partitioner included in the installer is designed to make exactly this scenario possible. However, no software in the world is bug-free, and critical data *must* be backed up anyway (regardless of any system reinstallations).